# Why is the error popping up in my output saying "TypeError: ApplicationCommandMixin.command() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

````py
import asyncio

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

from Economy.Systems.Economy import economy
from bot import currency, success_embed_colour, leader_embed

yaml = YAML()
with open("Configs/config.yml", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    config = yaml.load(file)

bot = discord.Bot

class leaderboard(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    # Leaderboard Command
    @bot.command(aliases=config['leaderboard_alias'])
    @commands.guild_only()
    async def leaderboard(self, ctx, leader_type=None):
        if leader_type is None:
            rankings = economy.find({"guildid": ctx.guild.id, "money": {"$exists": True}, "job_type": {"$exists": False}}).sort("money", -1)
            users = []
            money = []
            for x in rankings:
                users.append(x['name'])
                money.append(x['money'])
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title=f":trophy: {ctx.guild}'s Leaderboard",
                colour=leader_embed,

            )
            embed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.author}", icon_url=f"{ctx.author.avatar_url}")
            pagination = list(zip(users, money))
            pages = [pagination[i:i + 10] for i in range(0, len(pagination), 10)]
            page = 0
            num = 0
            user_list = []
            balance_list = []
            for i in pages:
                embed.clear_fields()
                for users, money in i:
                    num += 1
                    embed.add_field(name=f"#{num}: {users}", value=f"```{currency}{money:,}```", inline=True)
                embed.set_footer(text=f"Page {page + 1}/{len(pages)}")
                message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                page += 1
                await message.add_reaction("⬅️")
                await message.add_reaction("➡️")
                await message.add_reaction("❌")

                while True:
                    def check(reaction, user):
                        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["⬅️", "➡️",
                                                                              "❌"] and reaction.message.id == message.id

                    try:
                        reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60.0, check=check)

                        if str(reaction.emoji) == "⬅️":
                            if page == 1:
                                pass
                            else:
                                page -= 1
                                embed.clear_fields()
                                for users, money in pages[page - 1]:
                                    num -= 1
                                    user_list.append(users)
                                    balance_list.append(money)
                                for x in range(0, 10):
                                    embed.add_field(name=f"#{x + 1 + num - len(user_list)}: {user_list[x]}", value=f"```{currency}{balance_list[x]:,}```", inline=True)
                                user_list.clear()
                                balance_list.clear()
                                embed.set_footer(text=f"Page {page}/{len(pages)}")
                                await message.edit(embed=embed)
                                await message.remove_reaction("⬅️", user)
                                await message.remove_reaction("➡️", user)
                                await message.remove_reaction("❌", user)
                        elif str(reaction.emoji) == "➡️":
                            if page == len(pages):
                                pass
                            else:
                                page += 1
                                embed.clear_fields()
                                new_num = num
                                for users, money in pages[page - 1]:
                                    num += 1
                                    user_list.append(users)
                                    balance_list.append(money)
                                    embed.add_field(name=f"#{num}: {users}", value=f"```{currency}{money:,}```",
                                                    inline=True)
                                if len(user_list) != 10:
                                    get_ten = 10 - len(user_list)
                                    num += get_ten
                                user_list.clear()
                                balance_list.clear()
                                embed.set_footer(text=f"Page {page}/{len(pages)}")
                                await message.edit(embed=embed)
                                await message.remove_reaction("⬅️", user)
                                await message.remove_reaction("➡️", user)
                                await message.remove_reaction("❌", user)
                        elif str(reaction.emoji) == "❌":
                            await message.delete()
                            return
                    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                        await message.delete()
                        return

        elif leader_type.lower() == "global":
            rankings = economy.find(
                {"money": {"$exists": True}, "job_type": {"$exists": False}}).sort("money", -1)
            users = []
            money = []
            guild = []
            for x in rankings:
                users.append(x['name'])
                money.append(x['money'])
                guild.append(x['guildid'])
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title=f" Global Leaderboard",
                colour=leader_embed,

            )
            embed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.author}", icon_url=f"{ctx.author.avatar_url}")
            pagination = list(zip(users, money, guild))
            pages = [pagination[i:i + 10] for i in range(0, len(pagination), 10)]
            page = 0
            num = 0
            user_list = []
            balance_list = []
            guild_list = []
            for i in pages:
                embed.clear_fields()
                for users, money, guild in i:
                    num += 1
                    embed.add_field(name=f"#{num}: {users}\n`{self.bot.get_guild(guild)}`", value=f"```{currency}{money:,}```", inline=True)
                embed.set_footer(text=f"Page {page + 1}/{len(pages)}")
                message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                page += 1
                await message.add_reaction("⬅️")
                await message.add_reaction("➡️")
                await message.add_reaction("❌")

                while True:
                    def check(reaction, user):
                        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["⬅️", "➡️",
                                                                              "❌"] and reaction.message.id == message.id

                    try:
                        reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60.0, check=check)

                        if str(reaction.emoji) == "⬅️":
                            if page == 1:
                                pass
                            else:
                                page -= 1
                                embed.clear_fields()
                                for users, money, guild in pages[page - 1]:
                                    num -= 1
                                    user_list.append(users)
                                    balance_list.append(money)
                                    guild_list.append(guild)
                                for x in range(0, 10):
                                    embed.add_field(name=f"#{x + 1 + num - len(user_list)}: {user_list[x]}\n`{self.bot.get_guild(guild_list[x])}`",
                                                    value=f"```{currency}{balance_list[x]:,}```", inline=True)
                                user_list.clear()
                                balance_list.clear()
                                guild_list.clear()
                                embed.set_footer(text=f"Page {page}/{len(pages)}")
                                await message.edit(embed=embed)
                                await message.remove_reaction("⬅️", user)
                                await message.remove_reaction("➡️", user)
                                await message.remove_reaction("❌", user)
                        elif str(reaction.emoji) == "➡️":
                            if page == len(pages):
                                pass
                            else:
                                page += 1
                                embed.clear_fields()
                                new_num = num
                                for users, money, guild in pages[page - 1]:
                                    num += 1
                                    user_list.append(users)
                                    balance_list.append(money)
                                    guild_list.append(guild)
                                    embed.add_field(name=f"#{num}: {users}\n`{self.bot.get_guild(guild)}`", value=f"```{currency}{money:,}```",
                                                    inline=True)
                                if len(user_list) != 10:
                                    get_ten = 10 - len(user_list)
                                    num += get_ten
                                user_list.clear()
                                balance_list.clear()
                                guild_list.clear()
                                embed.set_footer(text=f"Page {page}/{len(pages)}")
                                await message.edit(embed=embed)
                                await message.remove_reaction("⬅️", user)
                                await message.remove_reaction("➡️", user)
                                await message.remove_reaction("❌", user)
                        elif str(reaction.emoji) == "❌":
                            await message.delete()
                            return
                    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                        await message.delete()
                        return



def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(leaderboard(bot))
````

output:

```
  File "g:\Code\Stuff to work on\1mag1n33 discord bot\Beluga-bot\Economy\leaderboard.py", line 16, in <module>
    class leaderboard(commands.Cog):
  File "g:\Code\Stuff to work on\1mag1n33 discord bot\Beluga-bot\Economy\leaderboard.py", line 21, in leaderboard
    @bot.command(aliases=config['leaderboard_alias'])
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: ApplicationCommandMixin.command() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
File "g:\Code\Stuff to work on\1mag1n33 discord bot\Beluga-bot\Economy\balance.py", line 7, in <module>
    from bot import currency
  File "g:\Code\Stuff to work on\1mag1n33 discord bot\Beluga-bot\bot.py", line 73, in <module>
    bot.load_extension(f"Economy.{fn[:-3]}")
```

I tried removing self in diffrent strings and moved the files around the same error poped up. Also trying to add the economy folder where it contains the leaderboard.py file using cogs,Any tips or tricks pls tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Commands in cogs work differently, and you seem to misunderstand how OOP works.

> ```py
> bot = discord.Bot
> ```

This won't work for many reasons. One being that this is a different variable than the main "Bot" instance you're running, so anything you do here has no effect in other places. Another being that this is just a class **name**, not an **instance**. You can't do much of anything with this...

As a result, `@bot.command()` is not called on an *instance*, so the default `self` parameter is never passed into it when it is invoked, which is what your error is telling you.

However, why is the `bot` variable even here? You don't need it for anything. The `Bot` instance is passed in through the `__init__` of your cog. If you need it, you can access it right there.

*discord.Bot also doesn't even exist, it's `commands.Bot`*

> ```py
> @bot.command(aliases=config['leaderboard_alias'])
> ```

Commands in cogs are made using the `@commands.command()` decorator instead of `@bot.command`. Read the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html#quick-example

> ```py
> def setup(bot):
>    bot.add_cog(leaderboard(bot))
> ```

Extension loading/unloading is now async. Read the migration guide: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous